# Elasticsearch query filter by unique field

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch, I have employees mapped, each employee belonging to some team. Every team should have a team leader and I need to validate that. Is there a way to search for every team on its own, but in one query, to verify it has an employee with the field "is_leader": true? I would like to get results of all teams lacking a team leader.

```
{
{
            "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Jade",
            "team": "A",
            "is_leader": false,
},
{
            "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Jack",
            "team": "A",
            "is_leader": false,
},
{           "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Sarah",
            "team": "A",
            "is_leader": true,
},
{           "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Jim",
            "team": "B",
            "is_leader": false,
},
{           "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Don",
            "team": "B",
            "is_leader": false,
},
{           "_type": "employee",
            "name": "Jess",
            "team": "B",
            "is_leader": false,
},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `terms` aggregation on the `team` field to separate all teams, and then use another `terms` sub-aggregation on the `is_leader` field. That way you'll get the count for leader vs not-leader for each team. The teams with 0 leader will stand out:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "teams": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "team"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "leaders": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "is_leader"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By default the size is 10, both at the hits level and the `terms` aggregation level. You can tune to your liking.

Comment: thanks! 
I failed to mention I need to run this query on indices with ~3 million docs and it can't deal with that size. I added size limitations:
  "size": 1000,
  "from": 1000
right before the last bracket. I understand it works with some sort of pagination but the problem is that it's not guaranteed that all employees of a certain team will be aggregated on the first "chunk" and then it's possible that some team will actually have a leader but it hasn't been aggregated yet and I will mistakenly mark that team as "leaderless". Am I right? Do you have any idea of a solution for that?

Comment: What's the cardinality of all teams?

Comment: cardinality of all teams can be also ~2 millions.

Comment: So you have like ~3 million employees in ~2 million teams? that's a huge org :-)

Comment: well I guess I didn't give the best example to my data :) just tried to make it as clear as possible...

Comment: Ok, but if you have 2 million teams each of which should have a leader, that also means you'd have ~2 million results in the aggregation. That's probably not going to work, then. Do you need to run this only one time or regularly ?

Comment: regularly unfortunately.

Comment: And what is the expectation in terms of response time? Do you expect to get the result immediately or could this also be run behind the scenes and take a bit longer?

Comment: The problem is not only the run time but also the result, from what I understood I can't use scan or scroll and the aggregation results would be fairly large. I found another way in the system to track changes so with every employee update I could verify the teams updated have team leaders so for now if it works out I will try and avoid this aggregation query since it seems an overreach. Thank you so much for your help!